# Provide method dependendies

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-2

In the documentation it says that @Provides methods may have dependencies on their own, like:

```
@Provides Pump providePump(Thermosiphon pump) {
  return pump;
}
```

What would change if I would write it like that:

```
@Provides Pump providePump() {
  return new Thermosiphon();
}
```

And in the first snipped: Where does the method get its pump from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation also shows the `Thermosiphon` class:

```
class Thermosiphon implements Pump {
  private final Heater heater;

  @Inject
  Thermosiphon(Heater heater) {
    this.heater = heater;
  }

  ...
}
```

The constructor of this class is annotated with `@Inject`. This lets Dagger know to use this Constructor whenever a `Thermosiphon` is necessary, and automatically supplies a `Heater` instance to it, so you don't have to.

It is perfectly fine for you to create a new `Thermospihon` instance yourself, but Dagger saves you the trouble by doing it like this. For example, you would need to get some `Heater` reference from somewhere if you do it manually. That is what Dagger is all about, so you don't have to do the tedious repetitive work.

Comment: I am still trying to wrap my head around this dagger stuff. So @Inject basically has two different meanings. If it annotates a field it means the injector injects that field. If it annotates a constructor it means it uses this constructor to inject this object somewhere else (and needed arguments into this constructor)?

Comment: @Kuno More or less. You can read [JSR 330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) (section 4) for detailed explanation of the `@Inject` annotation.

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst I don't quite follow you. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

These are effectively the same **IF** a new instance of Thermosiphon.class is created every time you request an instance. If it's a singleton (or scoped in any way), then we have a difference.

If you have the following, then the first example is an alias to the singleton.  The second example, however, will still create new instances every time.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Thermosiphon provideThermosiphon() {
  return new Thermosiphon();
}
```

Personally, I like the first approach better. Using the first approach, you could add or alter the provider later and adjust the scope or the state of the instance before it'a passed to the alias. It seems a little more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks for other beans declared in your module

For example:

```
@Module
public class MainModule {


    @Provides
    public EmailServiceApiGateway provideEmailServiceApiGateway() {
        return new EmailServiceApiGateway();
    }

    @Provides
    public EmailSendingActivityPresenter provideEmailSendingActivityPresenter(EmailServiceApiGateway emailServiceApiGateway) {
        return new EmailSendingActivityPresenterImpl(emailServiceApiGateway);
    }
}
```

So in the case above, EmailServiceApiGateway gets automatically injected into EmailSendingActivityPresenter.